# Criar novo array a partir das chaves de um hash

Tags: array, ruby, hash

Tenho o seguinte hash:

```
meu_hash = [
  {
    :nome => 'fiat 500',
    :complementos=> %w[gps bluetooth automatico],
    :ano=> '2021'
  },
  {
    :nome => 'fusca',
    :complementos=> %w[som dvd automatico],
    :ano=> '2022'
  }

]
```

Eu quero criar um novo array somente com a chave :ano, onde ficaria dessa forma:

```
 novo_array = [
 {
    :ano=> '2021'
  },
  {
    :ano=> '2022'
  }
]
```

Eu sou iniciante em Ruby e não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeira coisa a ser percebida é que o objeto referênciado por `meu_hash` não é um objeto [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Hash.html) veja o fragmento:

```
require 'pp'

meu_hash = [{:nome => 'fiat 500',:complementos=> %w[gps bluetooth automatico],:ano=> '2021'},{:nome => 'fusca',:complementos=> %w[som dvd automatico],:ano=> '2022'}]

pp meu_hash.class  #=> Imprime a classe qual deriva um objeto.
#=> Array
```

Então o seu objeto `meu_hash` na verdade é um objeto do tipo[`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html) povoado por objetos `Hash`.

- A iteração pelos elementos de um `Array` pode ser feita como o método [`Array.collect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-collect).
- A seleção de chaves específicas em um objetos `Hash` pode ser feita com o método [`Hash.slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice).

```
require 'pp'

meu_hash = [{:nome => 'fiat 500',:complementos=> %w[gps bluetooth automatico],:ano=> '2021'},{:nome => 'fusca',:complementos=> %w[som dvd automatico],:ano=> '2022'}]

pp meu_hash.collect {|e| e.slice(:ano) }  #=> Para cada elemento do array meu_hash retorna um novo objeto Hash ue contém apenas a o chave :ano
#=>[{:ano=>"2021"}, {:ano=>"2022"}]
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/WrCW1B)</sup>